How to stop the Spring batch job gracefully post app crash or DB restart
I am using spring boot application and spring batch for background job.
When I schedule to job, it is running. Suddenly application restart or DB restart is happening due to some reason.
Now, Spring batch job and step execution status is in STARTED OR UNKNOWN. I want to set it to FAILED Or STOPPED state to schedule the next job.
If i do using joboperator.stop(), it is not changing the status . So i have manual update the step and job table status.
Actually I have another endpoint to stop the running job using joboperator.stop() which will stop the running job.

Option 1: if i use same endpoint for above restart usecase, it is
not working.
Option 2: In multi node scenario, On app startup, I
find all running jobs and set status to stop using manual update.

Node 1 job scheduled
Node1 job is running Node2 restart happens

It will find job which is started by Node1 and set to STOPPED. It will create confusion in the DB status


Stopped status is updated
Node1 got error as

org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Attempt to update step execution id=119 with wrong version (2), where current
version is 2





I want to set status to STOPPED for job which are stuck by app restart or DB restart.
Let me know if you solution or workaround for this

If the job was killed abruptly, you need to update its status manually in the database. There is a note about this here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/job/advanced-meta-data.html#aborting-a-job
You need to set the status to FAILED and the END_TIME to a non null value in both the job execution and step execution tables.
